# Mount a ext4 partition on Mac OS X

Tags: linux, mac-osx, mount, ext4

Is it possible to mount a Linux ext4 partition on Mac OS X?

Please describe the procedure - risk free - thanks.

**Edit Aug 2012**

The best solution I found was to

- use a 2nd machine with Linux,
- mount on Linux the ext4 FS,
- [install NFS on Linux](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo) and export the folder,
- then [mount the NFS partition on Mac](http://ivanvillareal.com/osx/nfs-mac-osx-lion/).

Comment: Take a look at this related question http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29842/how-can-i-mount-an-ext4-file-system-on-os-x/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution couple of month ago. I bought this one https://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-mac/ and it works like a charm. And I didn't have a chance to find any free solution. ext4fuse is fine but for read-only mode.

Comment: I have two question with paragon's extfs software:
1) Do you still use it with recent versions of macOS (like Ventura 13.x or Sonoma 14.x)?
2) Have you ever used it along docker? plays nice with it? I mean like for example using a partition in ext4 created by Paragon's software and then place the docker project there making use of shared folders with the host. Asking because of the potential performance improvement if docker didn't use osxfs

Comment: 1) I did not use it for at least a half of year, so have no idea about MacOS Sonoma 14.x, but it work on Ventura 13.x.
I just checked on my Ventura 13.6 -> "extFS for Mac 11 by Paragon Software (11.7.373)" work fine.
2) No I didn't, sorry. But theoretically there shouldn't be any issues.

Answer (score 3):

It seems it isn't currently possible.

A possible workaround for some scenarios is explained at
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mac-os-x-read-ext3-ext4-external-usb-hard-disk-partition/

Answer (score 2):

Try [MacFuse](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/) with [ext4fuse](http://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse).  If you want it to be risk-free, mount it read-only or duplicate the partition first.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do it by running Linux in a Virtualbox VM. Only thing you'd stand to lose is time configuring and installing (And space on the drive). Certainly won't hurt the Mac to try it.